# MOSS Custom IRM protector in C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I need to develop a custom IRM protector for MOSS. There are very few documentation on this and all of them are in VC++. Can a custom IRM protector be developed in C#? If so where can I find samples of this?

Answer (score 1):

native code only I'm afraid. best sample is in the SDK